# 80% Rule Estimation Value in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

Assume a range of values inserted in a schema table and in the end of the month i want to apply for these records (i.e. 2500 rows = numeric values) the algorithm: sort the values descending (from the smallest to highest value) and then find the 80% value of the sorted column.

In my example, if each row increases by one starting from 1, the 80% value will be the 2000 row=value (=2500-2500*20/100). This algorithm needs to be implemented in a procedure where the number of rows is not constant, for example it can varries from 2500 to 1,000,000 per month

Comment: "descending" == from highest to smallest.... Yes?

Comment: I love homework questions, I particularly like watching them drift down my screen until they drop off the front page.

Comment: @Lazarus: I find it hard to tell the difference between a homework question and an obscure business query from the client. :)

Comment: @Adam Paynter - Client queries don't usually start with "Assume", academic questions have that tendency, especially when copied somewhat (ascending) verbatim.

Comment: @Lazarus: Excellent point! I didn't even notice the "assume"!

Comment: @Adam Paynter - Me == Pedant ;)

Comment: @Lazarus: Fair enough. :) I gave a hint, hopefully steering him in the right direction.

Comment: @veg123 After 14 questions you should really have accepted at least one of the answers. At least if any of them were useful

Comment: as long as the instructor accepts his (our) answers, he's ok i guess ;)

Comment: Clients, teachers, instructors. Some pay in cash, others with checks and others with grades.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a query using the [percentile_disc](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions111.htm) function to solve your problem. Sounds like it does what you want.

An example would be

```
select percentile_disc(0.8) within group (order by the_value)
from my_table
```

Comment: -1 This is not a worthwhile answer to the question.  If you think the question isn't worthy of a proper answer please don't bother posting anything at all.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: You can achieve this using Oracle's cumulative aggregate functions. For example, suppose your table looks like this:

```
     MY_TABLE
+-----+----------+
| ID  | QUANTITY |
+-----+----------+
|  A  |    1     |
|  B  |    2     |
|  C  |    3     |
|  D  |    4     |
|  E  |    5     |
|  F  |    6     |
|  G  |    7     |
|  H  |    8     |
|  I  |    9     |
|  J  |   10     |
+-----+----------+
```

At each row, you can sum the quantities so far using this:

```
SELECT
  id,
  quantity,
  SUM(quantity)
    OVER (ORDER BY quantity ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
      AS cumulative_quantity_so_far
FROM
  MY_TABLE
```

Giving you:

```
+-----+----------+----------------------------+
| ID  | QUANTITY | CUMULATIVE_QUANTITY_SO_FAR |
+-----+----------+----------------------------+
|  A  |    1     |              1             |
|  B  |    2     |              3             |
|  C  |    3     |              6             |
|  D  |    4     |             10             |
|  E  |    5     |             15             |
|  F  |    6     |             21             |
|  G  |    7     |             28             |
|  H  |    8     |             36             |
|  I  |    9     |             45             |
|  J  |   10     |             55             |
+-----+----------+----------------------------+
```

Hopefully this will help in your work.

Comment: A brave attempt to answer a really poorly worded question, gotta love stock trading ;)